# Listener when hovering view Android

Tags: android, hover, drawing, ontouchlistener

The user can draw over view (with a pencil) and i want a listener to know if the user was drawn over other views. When the user is drawing over a view, i want to change the view's color.
I tried with `OnTouchListener`, `OnHoverListener`, `OnFocusChangeListener` i also tried to override the method `onTouchEvent`, but none of these were called.

Screenshot of the sample:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeshN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should handle onTouchListener by calling ViewObject.setOnTouchListener the OnTouchListener passes to argument . The first is the Calling View and the second is a MotionEvent object . The motion event has a getAction() method than returns a integer you should write a if statement and check whether the getAction() value equals to MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN . In the block of the if statement write your code . Also you can handle unhover event by write another if statement and check whether the getAction() integer equals to MotionEvent.ACTION_UP and write another code in if block statement . Your problem will be solved completely.

Comment: I tried that, but the OnTouchListener of the blue views is not called only the OnTouchListener of the root layout is called. I think the root layout is consuming it